# Webpack - Cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've had a problem with webpack, after run `webpack --progress --color --config webpack.dev.js` I've had 184 errors like below:

```
ERROR in ./src/features/settings/SettingsNotificationsPage.tsx 2:0-107
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/features/settings/components/DashboardSettingsNavigation' in '...'
```

In my `SettingsNotificationsPage` i'm import `DashbaordSettingsNavigation` like here

```
import { DashboardSettingsNavigation } from "src/features/settings/components/DashboardSettingsNavigation";
```

and is correct but when webpack try to build my project then many of this import explode.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when using `src/` path in reactjs.

### Solutions

##### Without any additional config

Updating your src/ path with a relative import should do the trick.

*then your import became*

```
import { DashboardSettingsNavigation } from "./components/DashboardSettingsNavigation";
```

based on the fact your import is made from `/src/features/settings/SettingsNotificationsPage.tsx`

##### Adding/updating jsconfig/tsconfig as follow

If you add a js/ts configuration setting `baseUrl` to `"src"` you should be able to import `src/features/...` as `features/...` without the need of using relative import.

*Your `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json` should be something like*

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      ..., 
      "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

*then your import became*

```
import { DashboardSettingsNavigation } from "features/settings/components/DashboardSettingsNavigation";
```